# Apply function between lists of data frames

Tags: r, list, function, loops

I have 2 lists (**my.listA** and **my.listB**) in R including 3 data frames each:

```
da1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(4,5,6))
da2 <- data.frame(x=c(3,2,1),y=c(6,5,4))
da3 <- data.frame(x=c(5,4,1),y=c(8,5,7))
my.listA <- list(da1, da2, da3)

db1 <- data.frame(z=c(2))
db2 <- data.frame(z=c(3))
db3 <- data.frame(z=c(4))
my.listB <- list(db1, db2, db3)
```

I am trying to obtain a new list (**my.listAB**) so that it includes 3 data frames showing the element by element product of the data frames in **my.listA** and **my.listB** paired according to the number at the end of the data frames' names, that is, the product of elements in **da1** by elements in **db1**, the product of **da2** by **db2** and the product of **da3** by **db3**.

This would be my desired result:

```
dab1 <- data.frame(x=c(2,4,6),y=c(8,10,12))
dab2 <- data.frame(x=c(9,6,3),y=c(18,15,12))
dab3 <- data.frame(x=c(20,16,4),y=c(32,20,28))
my.listAB <- list(dab1 , dab2 , dab3)
```

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  my.listAB <- my.listA[[i]]*my.listB[[i]]
};
```

Ideally someone could guide me towards a solution using the lapply function?

Many thanks!

Comment: `lapply(1:3, function(x) my.listA[[x]] * my.listB[[x]]$z)` should work as well as `l <- list(); for (x in 1:3) l[[x]] <-  my.listA[[x]] * my.listB[[x]]$z`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @lukeA! Your code is elegant and straight to the point!

Comment: @lukeA, I am not sure how to acknowledge your help via the Stackoverflow voting buttons though. Any clues?

Comment: You're welcome. I posted an answer, which you can check if you like the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
l <- lapply(1:3, function(x) my.listA[[x]] * my.listB[[x]]$z)
```

or

```
l <- list() 
for (x in 1:3) 
  l[[x]] <- my.listA[[x]] * my.listB[[x]]$z
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `lapply` and `for` loop option suggested by @lukeA in the comments, you could also try `Map`

```
 r1 <- Map(`*`, my.listA,unlist(my.listB))
 identical(r1, my.listAB)
 #[1] TRUE
```